# How to find the match of identical values in two different columns of a dataset in python

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a dataset as a .txt file format which looks like the following:

```
# ID M R x y z
  0 1 200 2 2 2 
  1 5 300 2 4 6 
  2 5 600 2 4 2
  3 4 500 2 2 5
  4 4 500 3 2 1
  5 7 300 2 4 1
```

I want to print the ID of the rows who have identical values in both x and y columns

I wrote a piece which does nothing closeto  what I want:

```
import numpy as np
halo = 'test.txt'
ID, m,r,x,y,z= np.loadtxt(halo)


for yv in np.unique(halo[3] and halo[4]):
    if yv != np.nan:
        idx = x == yv

print idx
```

basically I want a output like the following:

```
[0, 3]
[1, 2, 5]
```

which encloses the ID column values of those with same values in both x and y. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_txt_file')
rows = df[df['x'] == df['y']]
```

where rows.index = [0, 3]

Comment: HI, It is not quite working for me yet, do i do `print rows.index' to print [0,3]?

Comment: yes, rows is a dataframe and it's index is the output you want. so print(rows.index)